# jquery how to pass variable from the last iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, recursion, iteration

I'm having an each loop though the objects,

And in it, I create some images, and I want to put into them a data of the reference to an image from the last iteration.

For example:

```
.each((function(some_data){ return function(i, obj){

    var prev='???'; // how do I retrieve the value from the last cycle?
    var image=new Image();
        image.data('prev',prev);
        prev=image;
                // how do I pass the value to next cycle?
    }})(some_data));
```

Comment: Put your `prev` definition out of `each` block.

Comment: Oh, I never thought of that... But it sounds like a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your .each call, you define the variable in the outer scope..

```
var prev=null;
collection.each(function(idx, val){
   alert("Prev should have value from previous iteration (or null):" + prev);
   var image=new Image();
   image.data('prev',prev);
   prev=image;
 })(some_data));
```

Comment: can I also pass i and obj variables from the each without using return function()?

Comment: Yes, I don't see the need for the function wrapper.  If you had to wait for the images to load in this loop then things would get more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

use a global value ouyside the jquery each scope.

```
myloopingvar=null;

 .each((function(some_data){ return function(i, obj){

if(loopingvar !=null) 
 {// do stuff
 }
 var image=new Image(); image.data('prev',prev); loopingvar=image }})(some_data));
```

Comment: Eww. Global. Ick. (When using the `var` approach, as per the other answer, when the code is *hopefully* inside another function, it will not pollute `window`.)

Comment: @pst One doesn't come to appreciate careful scoping until a night of bug hunting because of global namespace issues :p